# Pass selected data from one component to another in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have two component one is main header other is sub header I need to update sub header when main header is selected how to do it in react.

**Main header**

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
const [isNavExpanded, setIsNavExpanded] = useState(false);

const isExpanded = () => {
    setIsNavExpanded(!isNavExpanded);
}

const selectedHeader = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
}

const mainLinks = props.navlinks.map((link) => {
    return <li key={link.id}>
        <NavLink to={link.url} onClick={selectedHeader} activeClassName="active">{link.text}</NavLink>
    </li>
 })
}
```

**sub header**

```
const Layout = props => {
return (
    <>
        <Navbar navlinks={Nav_Links} />
        <SubNavBar />
        <main className={styles.main}>{props.children}</main>
    </>
  )
}
```

I need to pass selectedHeader value from Main header component to Sub header component

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant code you are working with in a [mcve]. What value do you need to pass from `NavBar` to `SubNavBar`? What is the end net result you are trying to accomplish? This smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Context**

1. Create a component which has a state inside and renders a context provider and provides its `state` and `setState` to its children.
2. Place the component you created where it wraps both your main header and sub header.
3. Read `setState` from the context and call it when you want.
4. Read the `state` from the context in another component.

**useLocation**

If you are using `react-router` there is a hook called `useLocation`. You can call it inside your sub header and get the current location. Then proceed accordingly.